# Appcelerator app crashing on Barcode.capture() line on iOS device

Tags: ios, appcelerator, qr-code, appcelerator-titanium

I need to read QR code in my app. So I am testing on the iOS device. I added module and I am using this example so far

[enter link description here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.barcode/master/ios/example/app.js)

App crashing on this line

```
Barcode.capture({
       animate: true,
       overlay: overlay,
       showCancel: false,
       showRectangle: false,
       keepOpen: true/*,
       acceptedFormats: [
           Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE
       ]*/
   });
```

I tried also without params like this `Barcode.capture();` but still crashing.

> SDK version is 6.0.1.GA
>
> ti.barcode version is 1.9.1

Comment: Have you included **NSCameraUsageDescription** in your tiapp.xml?

Comment: Thanks. NSCameraUsageDescription solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely if there is no log showing the crash then it is related to **NSCameraUsageDescription** key-value in tiapp.xml.

Add it like this:

```
<ios>
    <enable-launch-screen-storyboard>false</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>

            <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use your camera?</string>

            <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we save to your library?</string>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```